# Glassfish4 artifact deployment issue

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, glassfish-4

I have issue with Spring project deployment on Glassfish4 with Intellij Idea 12(13). But Tomcat deploys it normally. Haven't found similar issue.

I’ve setted war file for deployment, but server log shows next exception: 
**“Exception during lifecycle processing java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no web component by the name of default here.”**

In console is written next message:
**”Artifact CoonSpringSecurity.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Artifact CoonSpringSecurity.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.”**

Here is server settings:
[image]

What else files it is necessary to post?

**Web.xml**

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value><![CDATA[
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    ]]></param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

……………log mappings….